# Exception Handling with Kotlin Exposed - How to catch unique constraint violation exception?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I have added unique constraint on a column in my table. When the constraint is violated, it throws an exception which I am unable to catch and convey to the user.

`Exposed: Transaction attempt #0 failed: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO templates (created_at, is_deleted, name, sections) VALUES ('2018-10-03 16:31:25.732+05:30', 'FALSE', 'Template1', '[{"title":"Introduction"}]')
RETURNING * was aborted: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "templates_name_key"
  Detail: Key (name)=(Template1) already exists.  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.. Statement(s): INSERT INTO templates (created_at, is_deleted, name, sections) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
! org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "templates_name_key"
!   Detail: Key (name)=(Template1) already exists.`

- How to capture these kind of SQL exceptions with user readable message?
- Is there any best practices to catch these exceptions?
- Should we catch them inside transaction or outside? Is there any necessity like that?

Below is the snippet I tried.

```
return try {
    val template: TemplateSerializer = transaction {
        val newTemplate = Template.insert(request)
        TemplateSerializer.serialize(newTemplate)
    }
    Response.status(201).entity(template).build()
} catch (e: Exception) {
    if(e is SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException) {
        resourceLogger.error("SQL constraint violated")
    } else if(e is BatchUpdateException) {
        resourceLogger.error("SQL constraint violated")
    } else
        resourceLogger.error(e.message)
    Response.status(422).entity(mapOf("error" to true, "message" to "Insertion failed")).build()
}
```

The message `SQL constraint violated` is not printed at all. Tried multiple catch with different Exception classes too. Nothing worked.

Sending such generic error message is not helping.

Comment: Can you see the full stack trace?  That would confirm that the exception is thrown from the code you're checking (and not from code injected elsewhere, or code in another thread).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exposed throws `ExposedSQLException` which is a subtype of `SQLException` with possibility to access the latest executed query (possibly which cause original exception) via `causeByQueries()` funciton. Original exception is accessible via `cause` property.

```
return try {
    val template: TemplateSerializer = transaction {
        val newTemplate = Template.insert(request)
        TemplateSerializer.serialize(newTemplate)
    }
    Response.status(201).entity(template).build()
} catch (e: Exception) {
    val original = (e as? ExposedSQLException)?.cause
    when (original) {
      is SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException -> 
        resourceLogger.error("SQL constraint violated")
      is BatchUpdateException -> 
        resourceLogger.error("SQL constraint violated")
      else ->
        resourceLogger.error(e.message)
    }
Response.status(422).entity(mapOf("error" to true, "message" to "Insertion failed")).build()
```

Comment: For anyone else wondering if you can get the ERROR CODE that usually database raise, you can get it from `original.SQLState`.

Comment: Not sure if it is too much to ask. It would be great if the exception is more readable or has a specific structure like column, value and table instead of simply `ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "templates_name_key" Detail: Key (name)=(Template1) already exists`. In this case, it needs a regex based striping to know that column "name" already has value "Template1". That could be added for the future roadmap of Exposed. Thank you for the help.

Comment: 1. You don't need to use `original.SQLState` if you already cast exception to `ExpesedSQLException` because it delegates same fields to `original`. Just use `(e as? ExposedSQLException)?.SQLState`
2. I think that `ERROR...` is raised by a database and Exposed can do nothing with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for the `sqlState`.

It would look like:

```
try {
        userService.insertUser(user)
    } catch (e: ExposedSQLException) {

        val isUniqueConstraintError = e.sqlState == "23505"
    }
```

You can take the correct error codes from right there:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/errcodes-appendix.html